# can I install multiple ubuntu distros at once?

Tags: dual-boot

I've been looking at a Ubuntu thumb drive of mine, and it has a distros spot on it.  Can I use it to install multiple distros that I can multiboot to, or is that not possible?  (i don't mean variations, I mean releases.

Comment: Are you planning on installing apps, and save documents and such?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multisystem allows you to install multiple distros into USB stick. Check out for more info http://www.pendrivelinux.com/multiboot-create-a-multiboot-usb-from-linux/